# How we can write our custom JAAS login implementation read the encrypted password from jmx.passsword file for remote connection in ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic, jmx, jaas

Currently I configured remote connection in ActiveMQ. For broker configuration we need to provide the `jmx.access` and `jmx.password` file which in plain text.

```xml
<broker useJmx="true" persistent="false" xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">
    ...
    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="true">
            <property xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" name="environment">
                <map xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
                    <entry xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" key="jmx.remote.x.password.file" value="/conf/jmx.password"/>
                    <entry xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" key="jmx.remote.x.access.file" value="/conf/jmx.access"/>
                </map>
            </property>
        </managementContext>
    </managementContext>
    ...
</broker>
```

Now I want to write my own JAAS login module to support encrypted password & access file.

I created a `login.config` file in which I added custom login module to load while doing authentication.

```
MyLoginModule {
   com.common.security.authentication.EncryptedLoginModule REQUIRED;
};
```

I modified `activemq.xml` to add this JAAS login module.

```xml
<plugins>
    <jaasAuthenticationPlugin configuration="MyLoginModule" />
</plugins>
```

However, when I try to login it still uses `FileLoginModule` instead of the `EncryptedLoginModule` provided in `login.config`.

Comment: How is the `managementContext` configuration related to the JAAS configuration? As far as I can tell those are 100% independent of each other.

Comment: @JustinBertram if that is the case then how we can provide the encrypted password to the managementContext? As currently we are passing jmx.password file which contains the plain text data, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ uses the JDK's default JMX setup, so the standard JMX configuration properties apply.

Standard way to tell Java JDK which JAAS module to use for JMX:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.login.config=activemq
```

Additional changes are required in bin/activemq (if you use the Apache distribution), to add the slf4j and activemq-jaas.jar to the classpath.

You know you have the classpath problem if you get this message when running

```
jconsole -debug
```

Error message:

```
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModule found for org.apache.activemq.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule
```

These are the changes planned for this related JIRA:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-8391